# Как можно сохранить несколько переменных одним числом?

Tags: python

В **Python** я имею значения нескольких переменных:

```
x = 8
y = 3
isIntDivisionAvailable = True
```

как мне упаковать эти значения одним числом?(x и y остаются в пределах 127)

Comment: Что значит "упаковать одним числом"?

Comment: Так же как хранятся несколько цифр (остаются в пределах девяти) в одном числе.

Comment: то есть каждому набору значений в переменных присвоить одно чсло, и по этому числу уже определять изначальные значения. Нужен именно такой споосб хранения

Comment: Используйте сдвиги и побитовое ИЛИ, чтобы упаковать значения и сдвиги и побитовое И, чтобы распаковать.

Answer (score 6):

При x, y в диапазоне 0..127:

```
packed = y * 128 + x
...
y = packed // 128
x = packed % 128
```

или

```
y, x = divmod(packed, 128)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант со сдвигами, как я писал в комментарии:

```py
x = 8
y = 3
isIntDivisionAvailable = True

def pack(a, b, c):
    return a << (8+1) | b << 1 | c

def unpack(v):
    a = v >> (8+1)
    v -= a << (8+1)
    b = v >> 1
    c = bool(v & 1)
    return a, b, c

v = pack(x, y, isIntDivisionAvailable)
print(v)
x1, y1, i1 = unpack(v)
print(x1, y1, i1)
```

Вывод:

```
4103
8 3 True
```

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, почему бы не использовать удобные структуры данных. В Python что число - объект, что объект - объект. Просто создать класс (можно и словарь, но не так удобно) для хранения набора значений и обращаться к каждому числу внутри "пакета значений" по имени.

```
class ValPack():
    def __init__(self, x, y, isIntDivisionAvailable):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.isIntDivisionAvailable = isIntDivisionAvailable

    def __str__(self):
        return f'x = {s1.x}, y = {s1.y}, isIntDivisionAvailable = {s1.isIntDivisionAvailable}'


s1 = ValPack(8, 3, True)
s2 = ValPack(18, 13, True)
s3 = ValPack(3, 0, False)

print(s1)
```

```
x = 8, y = 3, isIntDivisionAvailable = True
```

Что удобно - можно хранить и не запутаться при использовании любого количества значений каких угодно типов.

Comment: Иногда такая упаковка всё же нужна бывает. Хотя безусловно полями объектов пользоваться гораздо удобнее.